How to configure Apache Tomcat 9 to set the timezone 'Europe/London' for GeoServer 2.22.5
I'm facing issue with Geoserver Date and time. When querying features on GeoServer, the geoserver displays a timeStamp that is one hour behind London Time. The below steps I did on Apache server for the Geoserver timezone settings.
{
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "features": [],
    "totalFeatures": 0,
    "numberMatched": 0,
    "numberReturned": 0,  
    "timeStamp": "2024-04-15T17:33:21.052Z",
    "crs": null
} 

The above feature result displays 17:33:21.052Z, instead of london time 18:33:21.052Z,There is a significant impact when querying features between two dates and time.

Create the setenv.bat file in the the Apache-Tomcat installation directory where the bin directory containing the startup scripts.

Created this file as file doesn't exist and it allows to set environment variables for Tomcat.

Added the timezone configuration inside setenv.bat (i.e. add the following line to set the timezone.)
  set "JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% -Duser.timezone=Europe/London"


Save the changes to setenv.bat


The following context-param tag is added to the web.xml file, which is in the WEB-INF directory in the GeoServer installation directory.
<context-param>
    <param-name>TIMEZONE</param-name>
    <param-value>Europe/London</param-value>
</context-param>


finally restarted the Apache Tomcat.

But the time-zone setting is still the same on Geoserver and the changes not reflecting at all.  It would be really helpful if we could come up with some ideas on how to configure the London timezone on Tomcat for Geoserver.

the Z on the end of your timestamp stands for GMT/UTC so it is not in London time!
